# Unable to connect to mysql database on WSO2

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 and trying to connect with MySQL database on a windows machine. I have followed the documents but still no luck. change the deployment.toml file as below

```
[database.apim_db]
type = mysql
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_gateway_api?autoReconnect=true
username = hide
password = hide
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

[database.shared_db]
type = mysql
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_gateway?autoReconnect=true"
username = hide
password = hide
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I have run the scripts as well on the database created above. below is the error

```
[2020-02-04 09:55:20,999]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Connected to mount at configregistry in 126ms
[2020-02-04 09:55:21,000]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Connected to mount at govregistry in 127ms
[2020-02-04 09:55:25,440] ERROR - TransactionManager Failed to start new registry transaction.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:905) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:80) [org.wso2.carbon.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.ja
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:505) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594) [org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: In APIM 3.0.0, you do not need to explicitly define the driver class name. And I see some configuration errors in the toml. Missing ' " ' in the values. Could you please check correcting that.

type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shareddb?useSSL=false"

Comment: I have the following setting in toml file and other than this i have not changed anything else
i have created wso2_gateway_api & wso2_gateway database and import the script from respective locations
[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_gateway_api?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false;"
username = "root"
password = "root123"


[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_gateway?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false;"
username = "root"
password = "root123"

Comment: with userSSL=false having following stack trace

TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-04 13:32:19,971] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234

Comment: issue solved...we need to add driver too with useSSL=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

issue is solved with the following url
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_gateway?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
and adding the driver too as below
driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"